# Проблема с установкой выбора строки QTableView и scrollTo() на строку

Tags: c++, qt

Прошу помочь разобраться с преобразованиями QModelIndex в Qt5.x.

Суть проблемы:
- есть БД на PostgreSQL откуда загружаются данные в собственную модель;
- общение с БД использует собственный движок, опирающийся на API lib_pq, стандартный интерфейс Qt не используется и использоваться не будет, поскольку очень кастрирован по возможностям. Свой обрабатывает и возникающие ошибки и, что самое главное для меня ловит EVENTS от сервера;
- соответственно, все модели наследуются от QAbstract....Model;
БД подразумевает, что к ней могут подключаться несколько операторов, и каждый через механизм EVENTS получает обновления от других. При этом программа автоматически подгружает изменения. Но если пользователь сам вводит какие либо данные требуется в QTableView, опирающуюся на модель перенести фокус ввода на только что вставленную строку.
При вставке в клиенте после подтверждения ввода исполняется код:

```
//-- для конкретного клиента вставляем в набор данных сразу, чтобы името возможность
//-- переместить указатель на только что вставленный элемент
auto idx = my_data_model->rowCount();
if (my_data_model->insertRow(idx))
{
  my_data_model->setData(my_data_model->index(idx,0),QVariant::fromValue(val->data_id));
  my_data_model->setData(my_data_model->index(idx,1),QVariant::fromValue(val->data_idn));
  my_data_model->setData(my_data_model->index(idx,2),QVariant::fromValue(val->data_name));
  my_data_model->setData(my_data_model->index(idx,3),QVariant::fromValue(val->data_note));
  my_data_model->setData(my_data_model->index(idx,4),QVariant::fromValue(val->data_par));
  my_data_model->setData(my_data_model->index(idx,5),QVariant::fromValue(val->data_code));
}
//-- генерируем сообщение
emit dataChanged(index(idx,0), index(idx,5));
emit innerDataInsert(index(idx,0));
```

Сигнал модели innerDataInsert - отправляет индекс вставленного элемента и в окне клиента обрабатывается как:

```
void win::innerDataInsert(const QModelIndex &index)
{
auto proxy = static_cast<QAbstractProxyModel*>(tbl->model());
//-- 1 и 3 - номера колонок с учетом видимости в QTableView
auto const proxyIndex = proxy->index(index.row(), 1);
auto const proxyIndex_e = proxy->index(index.row(), 3);
auto idx = proxy->mapToSource(proxyIndex);
auto idx_e = proxy->mapToSource(proxyIndex_e);
QItemSelection sel;
sel.select(idx, idx_e);
wed_selection->setCurrentIndex(idx, QItemSelectionModel::ClearAndSelect);
wed_selection->select(sel, QItemSelectionModel::ClearAndSelect);

auto h =proxy->mapFromSource(idx);
tbl->setCurrentIndex(h);
tbl->scrollTo(h);
tbl->setFocus();
}
```

Идея, как сказано выше заключается в установке выделения и скролле таблицы на только что вставленный элемент. Причем вставленный "собственноручно" а не тот который был вставлен кем-то и получен как сообщение от сервера.

При этом, разумеется сам QTableView использует модель данных с сортировкой. Инициализация производится:

```
wed_sf_proxy = new dataSortFilterProxyModel(); //-- подкорректированная модель с сортировкой
//-- порядок назначения моделей критичен! Сперва назначаем модель данных
//-- на proxy-модель
wed_sf_proxy->setSourceModel(my_data_model);
tbl->setModel(wed_sf_proxy);
wed_sf_proxy->setSortRole(myRole::SortRole);
//-- ... и только потом запрашиваем модель выбора
wed_selection = tbl->selectionModel();
```

где:
/// Модель выбора конкретного элемента
QItemSelectionModel* wed_selection;

tbl -> QTableView

Результат не устраивает. При вставке новой строки она конечно добавляется нормально с учетом сортировки, однако ни корректного выделения ни скролла таблицы не происходит. Попытка упростить задачу и попробовать следующее:

```
    void win::cmTest_Execute()
{
    for (int i = 0; i<50; i++)
    {
        auto proxy = static_cast<QAbstractProxyModel*>(tbl->model());
        auto const proxyIndex = proxy->index(i,1);
        auto const proxyIndex_e = proxy->index(i,3);
        auto idx = proxy->mapToSource(proxyIndex);
        auto idx_e = proxy->mapToSource(proxyIndex_e);
        auto h =proxy->mapFromSource(idx);
        QItemSelection sel;
        sel.select(idx,idx_e);
        wed_selection->setCurrentIndex(idx,QItemSelectionModel::ClearAndSelect);
        wed_selection->select(sel, QItemSelectionModel::ClearAndSelect);

        tbl->setCurrentIndex(h);
        tbl->scrollTo(h);
        tbl->setFocus();
        for (int i = 0; i<100000; i++)
            QApplication::processEvents();
    }
}
```

показывает, если данные отображаются штатно, без принудительной сортировки QTableView все работает правильно, но если отсортировать по любому полю, то перемещение происходит не скачками по таблице (как ожидалось после сортировки) а просто с первой по 50-ю запись отсортированной таблицы.
Где я косячу?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

И собственно ответ на свой вопрос я нашел сам. Дело в том, что код функции (с учетом первого фрагмента приведенного кода)

```
void win::innerDataInsert(const QModelIndex &index)
```

принимает на вход индекс самой модели, таким образом правильная ее реализация, с учетом преобразования индексов выглядит так:

```
void win::innerDataInsert(const QModelIndex &index)
{
    //-- для каждой конкретной таблицы определяем какие столбцы включены
    //-- (видимы) чтобы правильно сформировать индексы для выделения
    //-- иначе будут фокусы с отображением выделяемых ячеек
    int cnt = tbl->model()->columnCount();
    int colstart =-1;
    int colend = 1000;
    for (int i=0; i<cnt; i++)
    {
        if (!tbl->isColumnHidden(i))
        {
            if (colstart ==-1)
                colstart = i;
            colend = i;
        }
}

    //-- index - это QModelIndex модели данных
    auto idx = mod_data_model->index(index.row(), colstart);
    auto idx_e = mod_data_model->index(index.row(), colend);
    //-- преобразовываем его в QModelIndex модели сортировки
    auto proxy = static_cast<QAbstractProxyModel*>(tbl->model());
    auto const proxyIndex = proxy->mapFromSource(idx);
    auto const proxyIndex_e = proxy->mapFromSource(idx_e);
    QItemSelection sel;
    sel.select(proxyIndex,proxyIndex_e);
    wed_selection->setCurrentIndex(proxyIndex,QItemSelectionModel::ClearAndSelect);
    wed_selection->select(sel, QItemSelectionModel::ClearAndSelect);
    //-- после "выбора" proxyIndex преобразовываем в QModelIndex обратно в модель данных
    auto modelIdx =proxy->mapToSource(proxyIndex);
    tbl->setCurrentIndex(modelIdx);
    tbl->scrollTo(modelIdx);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем по поводу вопроса, тем не менее...
Вы не правы, штатные драйвера в Qt [умеют обрабатывать события](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qsqldriver.html#subscribeToNotification).

```
database.driver()->subscribeToNotification("MYEVENT");

QObject::connect(database.driver(), SIGNAL(notification(const QString&)), this, SLOT(database_Signal(const QString&)));
```

Непосредственно с postgres я не работал, но судя по исходникам драйвера, он поддерживает даже события с нагрузкой (payload)

Comment: Спасибо, конечно, но после пары спотыканий о другие ошибки я им не верю. проще самому ))) IMHO, разумеется. Свой код легче править.